# Using bnb Backup

Tags: typo3, backup

I'm trying to make backup of whole TYPO3 (4.6) based web page.
I have bnb Backup installed but when I click on it I get message:
Please include the static template of this extension and set "BackupDirectory"

I've found in manual tha I should add bnb backup to include tab in template.
But that didnt help :/

Any idea?

Comment: You say, you've included the static template now (include static from extensions). Did you also set the backup directory? I don't know bnb backup but did you rtm?

Comment: The BackupDirectory variable is set in constants.txt. I tried to change it to something different but with no successs. I need a tool to backup whole page with files and database to local drive from the backend level. Bnb backup seems to be the right tool but its not working :/

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways to create backups. Maybe this can help: https://wiki.typo3.org/Backup

You only need the database dump and the files. No magic.

Comment: I have only access to backend of Typo3 web site. So i can do DB backup from phpmyadmin, but what about files ? I can not find anywhere right tool to download all files from web site directory. I dont have access to SSH or ftp.

Comment: Every hoster gives you the possibility to access the files. There is nearly no extension for backups because everybody has this possibility. And I wouldn't trust such extensions. Ask the hoster or customer for access, otherwise I would reject this task.

You can't say a car mechanic that he have to switch the tires with only his hands.

Comment: If I had access to FTP or web site account I wouldnt bother asking for bnb backup. The problem is that I do not have access and I woun't have. A person who did create that site in typo3 cms and have access to web page site admin account is not more recheable. Now we need to backup all files and db in case something happens with actual hosting service. BNB Backup looks like the right tool. i really need help with running that extension or any other tool to download all web pige site files

Comment: If that´s such an old instance you could try the following:
But this is *definetely not* a common and recommended way to go. If something fails in the Extension Manager during the installation, this could break your site, as you would have to remove the extension I will recommend now by hand in the LocalConfiguration `extList`. Do not go on if you do not know what I mean here.
Otherwise you could try to install mw_shell or phpshell (find them outdated) an then push your files via SSH to your server.